# PySpark: GroupByKey and getting sum of a tuple of tuple

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this set of data:

```
[('Manhattan', ('East Village', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Theater District', 2)),
('Queens', ('Sunnyside', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Murray Hill', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Battery Park City', 2)),
('Queens', ('John F. Kennedy International Airport', 2)),
('Queens', ('LaGuardia Airport', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('NoHo', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Chinatown', 2)),
('Brooklyn', ('Brooklyn Heights', 2))]
```

What I aim to do is that for each borough, I want to get the top three highest neighborhoods with respect to sum.

The format of this data is

```
X = (Borough, (Neighborhood, total))
```

My thought process here is that:

I want to do a groupbykey on this data where I will first get all three boroughs, followed by the three highest neighborhoods, so the code:

```
X.groupByKey().mapValues(sum).collect()
```

However, as I understand this will give an error, because the second element is again a tuple, and I want to access the second element of this second tuple, which I'm not sure how to do that.

Also, this way, I would just get the data aggregated, so I wrote this piece of code that will give me the three highest neighborhoods:

```
def findingLargest(item):
    from heapq import nlargest
    i, j = item
    tops = nlargest(3, j,key=lambda x: x[1])
    return (i, tops)
```

So, the final code that I could come up with is:

```
X.groupByKey()\
 .map(findingLargest)
```

Expected output:

```
Borough, Top_1 Neighborhood, Top_1_count, Top_2 Neighborhood, Top_2_count
```

Any suggestions as to how do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it requires, at a time, to switch from `rdd` to use `DataFrame`. The most direct implementation would be to directly use `DataFrame`

```py
data = sc.parallelize([('Manhattan', ('East Village', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Theater District', 2)),
('Queens', ('Sunnyside', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Murray Hill', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Battery Park City', 2)),
('Queens', ('John F. Kennedy International Airport', 2)),
('Queens', ('LaGuardia Airport', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('NoHo', 2)),
('Manhattan', ('Chinatown', 2)),
('Brooklyn', ('Brooklyn Heights', 2))])
```

Transform your rdd in (key1_key2, value) format:

```py
data = data.map(lambda l: (l[0] + "_" + l[1][0], l[1][1]))
data.take(2)
# [('Manhattan_East Village', 2), ('Manhattan_Theater District', 2)]
```

Then aggregate:

```py
data = data.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
data.take(2)
# [('Manhattan_Theater District', 2), ('Queens_John F. Kennedy International Airport', 2)]
```

Split to get (key1, key2, value) format:

```py
data2 = data.map(lambda l: (l[0].split("_"), l[1]))
data2 = data2.map(lambda l: (l[0][0], l[0][1], l[1]))
data2.take(2)
# [('Manhattan', 'Theater District', 2), ('Queens', 'John F. Kennedy International Airport', 2)]
```

Selecting top n features will be easier with `DataFrame` API (in fact the first part would have been easier). I use a `window` function:

```py
df = data2.toDF(['district','neighbor','count'])
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
import pyspark.sql.window as psw

w = psw.Window.partitionBy('district').orderBy(psf.desc('count'))
df = (df.select(psf.col('*'), psf.row_number().over(w).alias('row_number'))
      .where(psf.col('row_number') <= 3)
     )
df.show(10)
+---------+--------------------+-----+----------+
| district|            neighbor|count|row_number|
+---------+--------------------+-----+----------+
|   Queens|John F. Kennedy I...|    2|         1|
|   Queens|   LaGuardia Airport|    2|         2|
|   Queens|           Sunnyside|    2|         3|
| Brooklyn|    Brooklyn Heights|    2|         1|
|Manhattan|    Theater District|    2|         1|
|Manhattan|           Chinatown|    2|         2|
|Manhattan|         Murray Hill|    2|         3|
+---------+--------------------+-----+----------+
```

To end-up with your desired output, one way to do that is switching back to `rdd`:

```py
df.rdd.map(lambda l: (l[0], (l[1], l[2]))).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y).take(2)
# [('Manhattan', ('Theater District', 2, 'Chinatown', 2, 'Murray Hill', 2)),
 ('Brooklyn', ('Brooklyn Heights', 2))]
```

Comment: Hi, please see the expected outcome, also, do you think you can suggest something via RDD?

Comment: I updated the answer to match the desired output format. I have not used rdd for a while so my memory is not fresh enough to propose a full rdd solution.

Comment: I keep getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' on this line: data = data.map(lambda l: (l[0] + "_" + l[1][0], l[1][1]))

Comment: The types of your data are not the same than in the example. You can try `data.map(lambda l: (str(l[0]) + "_" + str(l[1][0]), l[1][1]))`

Comment: Well, I got it working, however, the issue is that I keep getting neighborhoods for boroughs that don't even exist in those: ('Staten Island', ('John F. Kennedy International Airport', 415, 'Midtown', 385, 'Financial District', 257)) OR ('Bronx', ('Upper East Side', 9189, 'Midtown', 7943, 'Upper West Side', 7225)), I'm not sure what's going wrong here